# Change FPS during program execution in opencv Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, video-capture, video-processing

I am new to openCV and trying to record video using openCV. 
What I am doing is I want to slow down the video I recorded after few seconds . In short I want to mirror the iphone slow motion effect.
I am working on linux and using open cv Python. But I am not able to change the fps in the video recorded.

Can anyone help me with that?

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import time
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc,60.0, (848,480))
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret==True:
            frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)
            out.write(frame)
            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        else:
            break
    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: If you write the same frame twice then the video will be slow.

Answer (score 0):

In function VideoWritter 60.0 represent FPS, change the value it with 10 or 20.

Comment: I need to change the value dynamically during the program execution. i.e. from 60 to 30 and then back to 60. @Laurentieu